# Ratios of integers in Bezout's Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation, rational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Bezout's Identity is a classic of elementary number theory: let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then there are $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ with
$$
am+bn=1
$$With no loss of generality we can assume $m>n$ and take $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a<b$, and rewrite
$$
|am-bn|=1
$$My question is: can the minimal values of $a$ and $b$ be predicted by looking at the ratio $m/n$? My guess is that $b/a$ is in some sense the best approximation to $m/n$, maybe with the lowest possible value of $a$, or maybe $a$ is chosen such that $|m/n-b/a| \le a^{-p}$ for some power $p$.

Ex: $m=47,n=21$. Now $47/21 \approx 2.2381$: clearly $9/4=2.25$ is the 'closest' to this starting with denominator equal to $1$ and increasing, and indeed we have $a=4, b=9$ with $|4\cdot 47-9\cdot 21|=1$.

Ex: $m=101,n=58$. $101/58\approx 1.7414$; $a=4$ and $b=7$ with $b/a=1.75$ almost works with a RHS of $2$, but the actual pair is $a=27,b=47$ with $b/a\approx 1.7407$.

In summary: if we know $m/n$, can we use it to find $b/a$, and if so, what is the 'threshold' or degree of accuracy?

Comment: I think what is true is that $\frac ab$ is very close to $\frac mn$, the accuracy of which can be ascertained by noting that if $|am-bn| = 1$ then $|\frac{am}{bn} - 1| = \frac 1{bn}$ so $\frac{bn-1}{bn} \leq \frac{\frac mn}{\frac ba} \leq \frac{bn+1}{bn}$ (exactly one of the two will be an equality). So it's a good idea for sure. The trouble, though, is if it can be converted into an algorithm that performs better than the Euclidean algorithm, because given some rational number, finding a rational number close to it and with a small enough denominator looks difficult in isolation.

Comment: \begin{align*}
am+bn &= 1  \\
bn &= 1 - am  \\
\frac{b}{a} &= \frac{1}{an} - \frac{m}{n}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
So $b/a \approx -m/n$ with an error less than $1/n$.  So from $m/n = 300/103 \approx 3$, $b/a = -67/23 \approx -3$, $1/n = 0.0097{\dots}$ (so with error estimate ${}< 1/3 \%$), and $1/(an) = 0.000422{\dots} $(so actual error ${}< 1/10 \%$).  However, changing $n$ to $102$ causes a huge jump in $a$ and $b$, so "closest approximant" is unlikely to work...

Comment: @EricTowers like many arithmetic functions, I don't expect much to carry over between values for $n$ and $n+1$. I think Teresa's comment is more in line with what I had in mind.

Comment: This is related to [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations), but as Wikipedia mentions, in general, it's hard to beat the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: You write "maybe with the lowest possible value of $a$, or maybe $a$ is chosen such that $|m/n−b/a| \leq a^−p$ for some power $p$."  However, the two examples in my comment both satisfy $ {} \leq a^{-2}$ with their $m/n$s and with each other.  That is both $b/a$s approximate each other as well as any condition of the forms you contemplate.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah I think the Euclidean algorithm is probably more efficient, which means that unless one is particularly skilled with division this isn't very practical.